# http.server based Proxy server in front of Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to write python code which acts as a Proxy server in front of a Jupyter Notebook server. What I want is that after I launch the jupyter notebook on some port (e.g. 3889), instead of going through directly to the notebook (e.g. http://localhost:3889) I will instead go through the proxy service (i.e. http://localhost:8081). Currently, with the code attached below, I get the notebook to load, but some network calls from the browser are stuck on "pending".
What am I missing here?

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import requests

class ProxyHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    port = 3889

    def do_GET(self):
        resp = requests.get('http://localhost:{port}{path}'.format(port=self.port, path=self.path),
                            headers=self.headers)

        self.send_response(resp.status_code)
        for k, v in resp.headers.items():
            self.send_header(k, v)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(resp.content)

    def do_PUT(self):
        resp = requests.put('http://localhost:{port}{path}'.format(port=self.port, path=self.path),
                            data=self.rfile.read(),
                            headers=self.headers)
        self.send_response(resp.status_code)
        for k, v in resp.headers.items():
            self.send_header(k, v)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(resp.content)

    def do_POST(self):
        resp = requests.post('http://localhost:{port}{path}'.format(port=self.port, path=self.path),
                            data=self.rfile.read(),
                            headers=self.headers)
        self.send_response(resp.status_code)
        for k, v in resp.headers.items():
            self.send_header(k, v)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(resp.content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8081)
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, ProxyHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Here's the notebook loading nicely through the proxy:
[image]

But some major things are not working due to some stuck/pending requests:
[image]

The request in details:
(edit: I didn't include this information in the image but the request type of /api/sessions is "POST")
[image]